# Display Glitching on Ubuntu 20 LTS

Tags: display, scaling, hdpi

I've recently decided to run Ubuntu as my main OS on my laptop, however I've noticed this weird glitching occurring when I lock/sleep/suspend my laptop. It only occurs when the screen dims and I wake it up. Glitching stops when I restart the laptop. Its running Intel UHD graphics, and has 4k display. Not sure if that is important. I found few fixes for Nvidia graphics and similar issue occuring with Chrome however this seems to be more gnome based and I'm totally clueless as to where to even look or what could be causing the issue.

[Video of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeB8y.jpg)

[Dmesg Output](https://pastebin.pl/view/0a3ed775)

This is the graphics card.

```
lspci -nn | grep -E 'VGA|Display'

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 [8086:5917] (rev 07)
```

I've also made a [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/k37y78/display_glitching_on_ubuntu_2004/) and here's what I've already tried:

1. Running Kubuntu ([Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yn40n.jpg))
2. Running Fedora (same as above)
3. Tried different resolutions / scaling / refresh rates
4. [Tried this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/530748/how-to-force-hidpi-scaling-mode-on-boot-in-pop-os-gnome#530905)

NOTE: This laptop runs fine on windows, without any scaling issues and never had any display issues. It never had a Nvidia card and does not have any Nvidia drivers installed.

Comment: Please clarify your release(s).  Ubuntu uses *yy* releases only for specialist *snap* based releases for IoT appliances/devices or cloud based use (having done so since 2016). Main releases use *yy.mm* such as used by server & desktops releases.